# Is creating different executable components for a software good practice?

Tags: sockets, security, architecture, reliability

Suppose i am creating a software in Language A and some of the SDK i need is available in language B. So i create two executable and connect them using socket.

what are the issues that can come in terms of reliability and security ?

Is this architecture common in industry ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called a [remote procedure call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call). And it is pretty common.

Comment: What about security and reliability considerations? Some senior guy in my company told me that such program tends to break much often.

Comment: That depends entirely on the implementation. If you roll-your-own it will probably be insecure and unreliable. There are various standards, such as [Windows RPC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/rpc/rpc-start-page) or [ONC RPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Network_Computing_Remote_Procedure_Call). Also, webservices can be considered an RPC protocol.